# Add multiple mixins to one class with Jackson

Tags: java, json, mixins, jackson2

I have to minins:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.None.class,
                  property="@id")
public interface NoReferenceMixin {

}
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
              include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
              property="@class")
public interface FullClassInfoMixin { }
```

I want to apply both of these to a particular class, `Thing`.  It appears that I can only add one Mixin per class, as evidenced by experiment and the existing of `ObjectMapper.findMixInForClass` which returns a single `Class`.

I have tried making an interface that extends both:

```
public interface ThingMixins extends NoReferenceMixin, FullClassInfoMixin { }
```

`findMixInForClass` returns the mixing, but `FullClassInfoMixin` is not applied.  (It is harder to check if `NoReferenceMixin` is applied and I have not checked that.)

What is the correct way to do this?

I am using jackson 2.9.0.pr4

Answer (score 0):

Your work-around of having an interface that extends 2 interfaces you want to combine should work; annotations are scanned from specific mixin class throughout inheritance chain.

If you can reproduce the problem with simple example maybe file an issue against `jackson-databind`.